# Google's ReCaptcha Suddenly Stopped Working For All Sites

Tags: recaptcha, formmail

I've been using Google's Recaptcha in conjunction with Tectite FormMail on all of my sites and have noticed that it's suddenly stopped working on all sites.

I've checked the code and everything seems fine.
I've tried regenerating keys.
I'm using V2.0

Is any one aware of a problem with the recaptcha service and is there anywhere that you can check the status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To address this problem, Tectite have released an updated version of Formmail - version 9.14 - and advise that the MAXSTRING setting be changed to 2048.